# create folder tree with json and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a simple folder tree with JSON and javascript. I'm trying to divide menu in two columns one with folder icon and name that is wrap automatically if name is bigger than width of element (**word-wrap**) and second with the option icon that is vertically aligned based on the first column.

I try to use `<div class="row"><div class="col-10"></div><div class="col-2"></div></div>` but if I put **margin-left** or **padding** to subfolders the second column is not aligned correctly.

Like in this example:

```js
var folders_array = [{"idPadre":"","Miembros":"","nombre":"Carpeta sin titulo","idCarpeta":5},{"idPadre":5,"nombre":"Carpeta sin titulo2","idCarpeta":6,"Miembros":""},{"idPadre":"","Miembros":"","nombre":"Carpeta sin titulo","idCarpeta":7},{"idPadre":5,"Miembros":"","nombre":"Carpeta sin titulo","idCarpeta":8},{"idPadre":6,"nombre":"Carpeta sin titulo","idCarpeta":9,"Miembros":""}];

$(document).ready(function(){  
  show_folders(create_hierarchy(folders_array), $('.folder-list'));
});

function show_folders(hierarchy_array, $element){
  hierarchy_array.forEach(function(object){
    let parentID = object.idPadre;
    let folder_name = object.nombre;
    let children = object.children;
    let folderID = object.idCarpeta;
    
    if(parentID){
      parentID = object.idPadre;
    }else{
      parentID = undefined;
    }
    
    var $li = $('<li class="folder'+folderID+' f">\
                  <div class="row">\
                    <div class="col" title="'+folder_name+'"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i>'+folder_name+'</div>\
                    <div class="pl-2 pr-2 mt-1 folder-option" title="Options"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></div>\
                  </div>\
                </li>');
    
    $element.append($li);
    if(children) {
      var $ul = $('<ul style="padding:0; margin-left:10px"></ul>');
      $li.append($ul);
      show_folders(children, $ul);
    }

  });
  
  $(".f").on("click", function(e){
    open_folder = this.className.split(" ")[0].split("folder")[1];
    
  });
};

function create_hierarchy(folders_array){
  
  var parent = [], children = {};
  
  // find the top level nodes and hash the children based on parent
  folders_array.forEach(function(object){
    let obj = object, 
        parentID = obj.idPadre,
        target = !parentID ? parent : (children[parentID] || (children[parentID] = []));
    
    target.push(obj);
  });
  
  // function to recursively build the tree
  var find_children = function(parent){
    if(children[parent.idCarpeta]){
      parent.children = children[parent.idCarpeta];
      parent.children.forEach(function(object){
        find_children(object);
      });
    }
  }
  
  parent.forEach(function(object){
    find_children(object);
  });
  
  return parent;
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .folder-list{
    cursor: pointer;
    
  }
  .folder-list li{
    border: unset;
    user-select:none;
    list-style: none;
  }

</style>

<div class="col-6">
<ul class="folder-list" style="padding: 0;"></ul>
</div>
```

I also tried to use **table** instead of **ul** but this is what I get [CodePen](https://codepen.io/cplaiuu/pen/PoNOdaq) and this is what I want:

[image]

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using two datatypes in a object value? idPadre can be both string as number.

Comment: You are making it yourself way too hard for what it actually is. The jquery isn't helping. Just use template literals. I did some cleaning, the rest is up to you: https://jsfiddle.net/w1q6d5k8/1/

Comment: @JensIngels Thanks, I've never used template literals before, but it's a lot easier than what I'm doing.